# Good Samaritan law

Tags: legal-terms, legal-history

What exactly is the Good Samaritan law? Can someone please explain the Good Samaritan law? What is the Good Samaritan statute? How would someone apply the law in LaSalle County Illinois?

Edit: After reading some comments and answers, how would this apply in a situation where you were trained for cpr/first aid, called assistance to someone threatening suicide, and ended up with charges against you for assisting by calling for aid?

Comment: [Illinois statute](http://ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs3.asp?ActID=2076&ChapterID=58). Generally, if you're licensed (physician, dentist, EMT) or trained (had Red Cross training), and provide emergency care that you've been trained for, you're exempt from damages/lawsuit.

Comment: @mkennedy please don't answer in comments - answer in answers

Comment: I did not feel secure enough in my knowledge of the law to write an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In [Illinois](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs3.asp?ActID=2076&ChapterID=58):

> The General Assembly has established numerous protections for the
>   generous and compassionate acts of its citizens who volunteer their
>   time and talents to help others.

Basically, if you are a licensed medical profession, or have had successful training in CPR provided by the the American Red Cross or the American Heart Association, and you try in good faith to save somebody's life and fail, you are not liable for their death, under the assumption you did not cause harm in the first place (i.e. you can not stab someone in the chest, attempt CPR, and be exempt from lawsuit(s)).

Note that this doesn't apply to just CPR or physicians. This also covers dentists, Pharmacists, Optometrists, Physical Therapist, etc.

Comment: "its citizens": does that mean that those who aren't US citizens, or who are US citizens but are resident outside Illinois, are not protected?

Comment: @phoog that's a good question and I do not know the answer to that. Will research.

Comment: Actually, if you read the specific protections enacted in the code, as I have since posting that comment, they are expressed in general terms.  The expression of legislative purpose is perhaps problematic, but that should not have any effect on the application of the law. Also, exceptions to the protections concern misconduct in the commission of the protected act rather than other acts.